# IOS. Unable to close view after clicking my Info button (newbie)

Tags: ios5, modalviewcontroller

I have found some code for my infoButton which shows up my new credits.xib but **I can't manage to come back to my RootViewController**.
On my Credits.xib, I have linked my "Done" button with ToucheDown-FirstResponder-ToggleCredits Close.

Here is my code for the infoButton in my RootViewController.m in ViewDidLoad

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleCreditsOpen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *modalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:modalButton animated:YES];
//[button release];
[modalButton release];
```

and my code just after my ViewDidLoad

```
- (IBAction) toggleCreditsOpen:(id)inSender
{
    UIViewController *theController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Credits" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:theController animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction) toggleCreditsClosed:(id)inSender
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
    //[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I think I am missing something should I create a Credits.h and put the toggleCreditsClosed in it ?

Here is the stack trace

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7c67610> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DoneButton.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Here is my Credits.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Credits : UIViewController

{

    IBOutlet UIButton *DoneButton;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *DoneButton;

@end
```

and my Credits.m

```
#import "Credits.h"



@implementation Credits


@synthesize DoneButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    }



- (IBAction) toggleCreditsClosed:(id)inSender
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

If a delete the DoneButton link, the Credits view shows up but I it's when I press the Done button that I have a problem

```
Costumes[402:11f03] -[UIViewController toggleCreditsClosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a4c460
2012-10-24 22:19:33.271 Costumes[402:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController toggleCreditsClosed:]:
```

Sorry but I don't understand what I have to do and I cannot upload an image to show you but
in Outlets the link is (view<->View) and in Received Actions (toggleCreditsClosed:<->Button-Done Touch Down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome on SO !

Yes, you should create a separate .h / .m for your Credits. Then tell Inteface Builder that your .xib is a Credits class. Then link your button to this .h with the action you want. Basically, your last method should be in Credits.m :

```
- (IBAction) toggleCreditsClosed:(id)inSender
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Watch out, you dismiss the modal view with **self** instead of self.parentViewController in your code !

(PS : answers you'll get may not always work. Don't hesitate to comment, telling us what (didn't) work !)

Comment: I have an error:int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);  ->signal SIGABRT. I have put the .xib as a Credits class. The Outlets are linked (DoneButton<->Button and view<->view) and in receivedActions I have (toggleCreditsClosed<->Button Touch Down)

Comment: The errors comes when I click on the Info Button, when showing up the Credit view

Comment: Make sure you delete the previous link you had set with * toggleCreditsClosed:*. I don't think it's causing the error but it's a thing I always forget. This most likely comes from a too high number of *release*. You should make sure that when you call **[anObject release];** it's really needed. Can you update your question with the stack trace ?

Comment: Check your *DoneButton*. I think you previously created an IBOutlet from your xib to a .h, then deleted it in the code, so the link is still here. Try to remember where you used that variable name and select the xib. Then go to the last tab in the right bar and delete the link. Let me know if you find it !

Comment: stack trace uploaded. I'm stuck. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I think there's missing some text at the end, lol. Are you sure your button is linked to the correct *toggleCreditsClosed:* ? I mean, it may still be connected to the old one. I'd suggest removing the link and link again from Credits.h. Also, I would preferably use "Touch up inside" as the action, so you don't close the view when the user starts touching the button, but when he removes his finger from the screen.

Comment: There is only one toggleCreditsClosed (in Credits.m) the other one has been deleted. ARe my Credits.m and Credits.h correct ?

Comment: Whoa how could we miss that, lol. In your Credits.h, there's missing the declaration of *toggleCreditsClosed*. Add the line **- (IBAction) toggleCreditsClosed:(id)inSender;** between the *@property* and *@end*. Otherwise you con't be able to call the method...

Comment: nope I thought it was the good one but still Costumes[944:11f03] -[UIViewController toggleCreditsClosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c89bd0
2012-10-24 23:36:34.236 Costumes[944:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController toggleCreditsClosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c89bd0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Oh, it comes from your class Costumes. You're trying to call *toggleCreditsClosed:* on a Costumes class. Make sure your xib is from the Credits class.

Comment: it is, on the xib in Custom Class, in the field Class I have "Credits"

Comment: Do you have a *Costumes* xib ? Is there a link from a button to something ?

Comment: I do not have a Costumes.xib. In Outlets if a put the link (DoneButton<->Button-Done) I have an error loading the Credits View and if do not have this link I have an error when pressing the (Button-Done). I have a link in ReceivedActions (toggleCreditsClosed:<->Button-Done Touch Inside)

Comment: With (DoneButton<->Button-Done) I have the following error 2012-10-24 23:53:51.120 Costumes[1113:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x788f5f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DoneButton.'

Comment: All right. My advice: remove **all** references to all the buttons that close the views if you have several (in you xib, the properties **and** methods in all your .h/.m files (Credits, Costumes, ...), the links in the right bar when editing your xib, everything). Then start again. Add the button, link an outlet and a method ("Touch up inside" action) to Credits.h, and complete the method in the .m. Remember to save/clean your project while doing so, and make sure that when you have removed everything, it doesn't crash (doesn't work, but doesn't crash). Let me know when you're done.

Comment: I've solved my problem. I replaced in - (IBAction) toggleCreditsOpen the "presentModalViewController" by "pushViewController". As so, I have my navigation bar to come back to my menu and I don't use a "Done" button. thank you for your patience and help !

Comment: Good thing you solved it. Remember you can vote for answers, and accept one when your problem is solved !